# Is Atlas down? I can not get any response from Altas

Tags: atlas

During last 24 hr Atlas seems to be down. What is the problem? All I get is this response from Atlas.

> No Results found!
>
> No Tor relays or bridges matched your query :(

Comment: It is down for me as well (Dec 6, 2014, 1700 CET). I have Pacman for a minute or so and then the same response you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, please see the following ticket...

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13905